# How can I give another user read/write access to a specific sub folder and the ability to ls the tree but only for the folder they have access to?

Tags: linux, permissions, acl, setfacl

I have a user `user1` that has a bunch of folders in their home directory, including `/home/user1/data/special/files`.

I have another user `user2`.

I want:

- `user2` to be able to read/write files/folders in `/home/user1/data/special/files`
- `user2` to be able to `ls`:

  - `/` and see `/home`
  - `/home` and see `/home/user1`
  - `/home/user1` and see `/home/user1/data` but not other files/folders in `/home/user1`
  - `/home/user1/data` and see `/home/user1/data/special` but not other files/folders in `/home/user1/data`
  - `/home/user1/data/special` and see `/home/user1/data/special/files` but not other files/folders in `/home/user1/data/special`

I used `setfacl` to set permissions to `/home/user1/data/special/files` but it does not let them browse the path.

```
sudo setfacl -Rm d:u:user1:rwx,u:user1:rwx /home/user1/data/special/files
```

I do not want to hange the user/group owner of any of these folders because they ultimately should belong to `user1`.

If it helps, here are more specific details.

I'm using a web app/service running on this box. The web app/service is running as `user2`. In the web app/service, I have to browse/navigate to a folder with the files I want to see. So I have to go to:

1. `/` then
2. `/home` then
3. `/home/user1` then
4. `/home/user1/data` then
5. `/home/user1/data/special` then
6. `/home/user1/data/special/files`

I cannot just enter `/home/user1/data/special/files`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible.

```
chown -R user1:user1 /home/user1
```

This step will make you the owner of /home/user1 and all underlying directories.

```
chmod 755 /home/user1
chmod 700 /home/user1/data
chmod 700 /home/user1/data/special
chmod 700 /home/user1/data/special/files
```

And this sets the necessary permission, 755 means the user has rwx(7) and the others have only rw(5) access. This is necessary, so that they can traverse your home directory.

```
setfacl -Rm u:user2:rwx /home/user1/data/special/files
setfacl -Rdm u:user2:rwx /home/user1/data/special/files
```

With these settings, user2 will be able to read and write files in /home/user1/data/special/files. Additionally, user2 will be able to traverse the directory tree from / to /home/user1/data/special/files and see the relevant directories along the way.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked. I was hoping to avoid giving `other` any access to `/home/user1` but I guess there is no way around that.